# How to characterize Abelian sheaves that are quasi-coherent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a scheme. Suppose you are given a sheaf of Abelian groups $\mathcal{A}$ over $X$. How can you determine if $\mathcal{A}$ is the underlying Abelian sheaf of a sheaf of $O_X$-modules? In other words, is it possible to characterize in some (interesting) way the essential image of the forgetful functor from $Mod(O_X)$ to $Ab(X)$?

I'm not sure a non-tautological answer exists...

Comment: Did you mean that you need a definition other than the one on Hartshorne?  What do you mean by being non-tautological?  

Comment: Note that all curves (over a fixed algebraically closed field say) are homemorophic in the Zariski topology. Hence you can take a quasi-coherent sheaf on one curve and then transfer it by a homeomorphism to another curve where it very rarely will come from a quasi-coherent sheaf. This makes it very unlikely that there is any kind of reasonable description of the essential image (other than the tautological one).

Comment: Torsten- Are you sure that the isomorphism type of (say) the structure sheaf of a curve depends on the complex structure of the curve as a sheaf of a abelian groups?  I'm not convinced either way.

Comment: @Ben: Good question, it made me come up with an answer. On affine curves (and on $\mathbb P^1$) the first cohomology cohomology group of the structure sheaf is zero but on other curves it isn't (if one considers $k$-sheaves instead of sheaves of abelian groups one can even recover the genus of a smooth and proper curve).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) There is a very simple example that shows that it is impossible to answer the question of whether $\mathcal{A}$ comes from a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ if all one is given is the underlying topological space $|X|$ and $\mathcal{A}$ as a sheaf on $|X|$.  Namely, if $|X|$ is a point and $\mathcal{A}$ is such that $\mathcal{A}(|X|)=\mathbf{Q}$, then either outcome is possible: the answer is YES if $X=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{Q}$, but NO if $X=\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{F}_p$.

2) There are some nontrivial *necessary* conditions that one can state in terms of the topological space and the sheaf of abelian groups alone.  For example, in order for $\mathcal{A}$ to come from a quasi-coherent sheaf, there must exist an open covering $(U_i)$ of $|X|$ such that the sheaf $\mathcal{A}|_{U_i}$ on $U_i$ is acyclic for every $i$.

3) The condition in 2) is definitely not sufficient, even if the scheme structure on $|X|$ is not specified in advance.  For instance the constant sheaf $\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}$ on a point is acyclic, but it cannot be a quasi-coherent sheaf for any scheme structure on the point.

Comment: These minimalist examples are real mathematical haikus: thanks, Bjorn.